# Why the interpreter complains that library named "math" does not exist?

Tags: lua

Why the interpreter complains that library named "math" does not exist?

As far as I know, this library is loaded when invoking `luaL_newstate` on Lua-5.3.5.

```
#include "lua.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <assert.h>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    struct lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();

    int ret;

    std::string fileName("co.lua");
    if(fileName.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "the filename is empty" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::ifstream fileScript(fileName, fileScript.in|std::ios::ate);

    if(!fileScript.is_open())
    {
        std::cout << "open file failed" << std::endl;
        return -2;
    }

    size_t size = fileScript.tellg();

    if(size <= 0)
    {
        std::cout << "file has no valid content" << std::endl;
        return -3;
    }

    std::string textCont(size, '\0');

    fileScript.seekg(0);
    fileScript.read(&textCont[0], size);

    if((ret=luaL_loadbuffer(L, textCont.data(), textCont.length(), "co.lua")) == LUA_OK)
    {
        if((ret=lua_pcall(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET, 0)) != LUA_OK)   
        {
            std::cout << "error in invoking lua_pcall():" << ret << std::endl;
            if(lua_isstring(L, -1))
            {
                const char *errMsg = lua_tostring(L, -1);
                lua_pop(L, 1);
                std::cout << "script run encounter err:" << errMsg << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code snippet(it's very simple) for the file named "co.lua":

```
  a = 1;
  b=2;

  a=a+1;
  math.sin(a)
```

Here is the error message in the console:

```
error in invoking lua_pcall():2
script run encounter err:[string "co.lua"]:29: attempt to index a nil value (global 'math')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation states](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#6) that you need to call `luaL_openlibs` or `luaL_requiref` which does not seem to be the case with your posted program.

> To have access to these libraries, the C host program should call the `luaL_openlibs` function, which opens all standard libraries.

Alternatively (emphasis mine):

> Alternatively, the host program can open them individually by using `luaL_requiref` to call:
>
> - `luaopen_base` (for the basic library)
> - `luaopen_package` (for the package library)
> - `luaopen_coroutine` (for the coroutine library)
> - `luaopen_string` (for the string library)
> - `luaopen_utf8` (for the UTF8 library)
> - `luaopen_table` (for the table library)
> - **`luaopen_math` (for the mathematical library)**
> - `luaopen_io` (for the I/O library)
> - `luaopen_os` (for the operating system library)
> - `luaopen_debug` (for the debug library).
>   These functions are declared in `lualib.h`.

So change your program's first few lines to something like below.

[You also need to compare the return value](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#4.6) from `luaL_newstate` with `NULL` and handle that error condition.

```
int main()
{
    struct lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    if( L == NULL ) {
        puts( "Lua failed to initialize." );
        exit(1);
    }

    luaL_openlibs( L );

    // etc
```